# How can I use the same string created by password-generator in different places?

Tags: javascript, passwords

So I am stuck here where I need to use the value generated by `generatePass()` function. I need to obtain the same value of `witPass` in `newPass` to the same variable used in `witclick()` function.But I get different values because the generatePass function is called again generating a different random value.
I hope I am clear in explaining my issue since it's my first question.

````
```loginFunctions.js```
var passwordHolder = document.querySelector('#passwordholder);
var password;
var witPass;
witPass=password=generatePass();

//newPass is invoked when generatePassword button is clicked
function newPass() {
  passwordHolder.textContent = password;
  console.log(password);
  console.log(witPass);
  return witPass;
}

//function to generate random password
function generatePass() {
  var length = 8,
    charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
    retVal = "";
  for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
    retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }
  //witPass1=retVal;
  return retVal;
}
//witness login button click event
function witclick() {
  console.log('witclick invoked');
  witnessEmail = document.getElementById('witnessEmail').value;
  witnessPassword = document.getElementById('witnessPassword').value;
  console.log(witnessPassword);
  console.log(witPass);
}
````

`index.html`

```
  <!--send mail to witness by admin -->
  <div id="sendMail" class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col m-3">
        <form class="border border-dark rounded bg-dark  text-light">
          <div class="form-group px-2">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input id="mailid" type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small class="form-text text-muted ">Enter a Valid Email Address</small>
          </div>
          <strong><p id="passwordHolder">Password</p></strong>
          <button id="sendCred" class="btn btn-danger p-2 m-2" type="button">send cred</button>
          <button id="generatePassword" onclick="newPass()" class="btn btn-danger p-2 m-2" type="button">Generate Password</button>
          <button id="backToButtons" class="btn btn-danger p-2 m-2" type="button">Back</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--     witness login form-->
      <div id="witnessForm" class="col-md-6 m-2 ">
        <form action="" class="border border-dark rounded bg-dark  text-light">
          <!-- <div class="form-group px-2">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
          </div> -->
          <div class="form-group px-2">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="witnessEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small class="form-text text-muted ">Enter a Valid Email Address</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group px-2">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="witnessPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <button id="witnessFormLogin" onclick="witclick()" class="btn btn-danger p-2 m-2" type="button">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: pls post whole working code. This is not complete.

Comment: do you need the html file as well?

Comment: yes the ```HTML``` and complete js code you have used against the problem

Comment: i have uploaded html and js code ...